# Picnet table Filter doesnt work with pagination

Tags: pagination, tablefilter

I'm using "Picnet Table filter" for filtering my tables. I've 10000 records in my tables and using Dreamweaver pagination. I show 25 records per page. but table filter works for current page.

Is there any way we can make "Picnet Table filter" to filter the data on the entire list rather than in just the page?